# VB.NET This Program Output

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim k As Double
    For k = 1.0 To 2.0 Step 0.2
        MsgBox(k)
    Next
    MsgBox(k)
```

This program gives 2.2 output, why does the following program give 2.1 output as output

```
Dim k As Double
    For k = 1.0 To 2.0 Step 0.1
        MsgBox(k)
    Next
    MsgBox(k)
```

Comment: I voted for reopening, since the referenced question is a `C#` question. Here we have a `VB` question.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the code is [easily translatable to C#](http://converter.telerik.com).

Comment: An exact duplicate should refer to the same language. It is easily translatable for you, but not for an OP with 1 point on SO.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes hence the reason I've included the link....